# what is the syntax for ie driver in nunit C# code to launch internet explorer

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit, selenium-webdriver

MY code looks like below

```
public class ReviewCase
{
    private IWebDriver driver;
    private StringBuilder verificationErrors;
    private string baseURL;
    private bool acceptNextAlert = true;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetupTest()
    {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        baseURL = "http://rcm-bpmt.apmoller.net";
        verificationErrors = new StringBuilder();
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void TeardownTest()
    {
        try
        {
            driver.Quit();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // Ignore errors if unable to close the browser
        }
        Assert.AreEqual("", verificationErrors.ToString());
    }
```

Now i want to run the same code in internet explorer. Please provide me the code snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change:

```
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

to:

```
driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
```

You then need to ensure that the [IEDriver](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/detail?name=IEDriverServer_Win32_2.37.0.zip&can=2&q=) (application used to drive IE automation in Selenium) is unzipped to the project's main root directory.